# Using QComboBox with QSqlQueryModel

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt4, qcombobox

To speed-up `QComboBox` work with very big data set want to try to use `QSqlQueryModel` instead of `QStandardItemModel`. However text data in `QComboBox` I need to map to an ID, which is stored and accessible currently by `itemData(rowIndex, Qt::UserRole)`. In `QSqlQueryModel` query there will be 2 columns: ID and Text; and `QComboBox setModelColumn(1)` is defined, i.e. Text.

How to correctly subclass or redefine `QSqlQueryModel`, if `combobox->itemData(rowIndex, Qt::UserRole)` have to contain ID? Who had implemented such things or know link to a source? If I define `QVariant QSqlQueryModel::data(const QModelIndex & item, int role = Qt::DisplayRole)` in a such way:

```
QVariant MySqlModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(role == Qt::UserRole && index.column() == 1)
         return QSqlQueryModel::data(this->index(index.row(), 0), Qt::DisplayRole);

    return QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
}
```

will it work, i.e. whether `combobox->itemData(rowIndex, Qt::UserRole)` will contain ID in this case? Or need to investigate Qt sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, according to QComboBox code should work:

```
QVariant QComboBox::itemData(int index, int role) const
{
    Q_D(const QComboBox);
    QModelIndex mi = d->model->index(index, d->modelColumn, d->root);
    return d->model->data(mi, role);
}
```

Will implement this.